# How to restart telegram bot when it crashed due to some error or server restart?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I have developed a telegram bot by using python language. Now, I have to start the bot manually in SSH every day because the server will restart automatically every night. Therefore, the bot will stop when the server is stop. May I know what should I do to make the bot automatically start after the server is restarts ?

Comment: If you use linux for your server you can check init.d (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-linux-service-to-start-automatically-after-a-crash-or-reboot-part-1-practical-examples).
If it's windows, have a look for Automatic (https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/service-startup-automatic-vs-automatic-delayed-start/).
You can also find more solutions on the web.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Linux, you can use a command called crontab

generally crontab is used for scheduling and auto starting an events.

commonly command is:

```
* * * * * python ~/code/python-task-automation/test.py
```

for more details check out [this link](https://www.python-engineer.com/posts/cron-jobs-for-python/).